# Javascript is in Generated HTML, but none of the javascript works

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm in a rails 3.2 app, and I'm using the gem for skroller https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

My application.js requires skroller

```
//= require jquery-1.9.1.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.numeric
//= require skrollr
```

...and my generated html includes the expected javascript

```
<script src="/assets/skrollr.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The gem is supposed to allow you to use html5 tags to create some scrolling effects, the example one they give is

```
 <div data-0="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);" data-500="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);">
      WOOOT
    </div>
```

I placed this in the view to test it out, but even though the correct script is generating, it's simply not working and I can't figure out why

My assumption is that since it's generating, then it's nothing to do with how i setup the views or application.js... looking for any help, thanks

Comment: Does your browser's console show any errors? Do you get the correct file if you open `/assets/skrollr.js?body=1` manually?

Comment: No errors, the file is also the correct one when I open it manually

Comment: Okay I think I may have foudn the problem although not a solution yet... when I looked at the web console for their example, it has a "  <script type="text/javascript">
  var s = skrollr.init();
  </script>"    whereas my html doesn't render that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell skrollr to initialize itself.

Add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    skrollr.init();
});
</script>
```

somewhere after you load the external files.

There are many options available to you here too. See: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#skrollrinitoptions